# Trying to compile solidity token contract but keep getting compile error

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, contract

I keep getting this compiler error:

```
CompileError: openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:61:41: ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'
    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
                                        ^------^
```

Here is my contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/DetailedERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";
    
    contract TestToken is Standard, DetailedERC20 {

        uint256 public totalSupply;

        constructor(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals) 
            DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, _decimals) 
            public 
            {

            }
}
```

Here is the ERC20 contract code:

```
contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    /**
     * @dev Sets the values for {name} and {symbol}.
     *
     * The defaut value of {decimals} is 18. To select a different value for
     * {decimals} you should overload it.
     *
     * All two of these values are immutable: they can only be set once during
     * construction.
     */
    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the name of the token.
     */
    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the symbol of the token, usually a shorter version of the
     * name.
     */
    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure that is the one causing this specific error but what is the "**" doing in from of "function name()" and after "return **_name";

Comment: What version of openzeppelin are you using? I can't find StandardToken.sol on the github.

Comment: I am using version 0.5.16

Comment: Those "**" were added when I add the question to the network.

Comment: Here is the Standard Token contract:

Comment: @MattMan Since you stated that the `**` signs around the `name()` function are not part of the original code (my guess is that your intention was to format the function in bold text, but formatting is not available inside the `code` block), I edited your question and removed them.

Answer (score 0):

I got to work, it was making sure that the solidity compiler was up to date!  My solidity compiler is version 0.8.6 and the compiler I had listed in my truffle-configuration file was 0.5.16